# Программа должна дождаться ввода текста в окно 2.Работа с исключениями Python

Tags: python, исключения, tkinter

Суть программы в том что при вводе текста 'плохая' в окно1 и нажатие кнопки пуск запуска программы срабатывает исключение,а дальше программы должна ДОЖДАТЬСЯ ввода текста в окно2 и при нажатие кнопки ввод2 программа должна продолжить своё выполнение.Вопрос,как сделать что-бы программа дождалась ввода текста в окно2 и продолжила своё выполнение при нажатие кнопки ввод2? Две кнопки и исключения обязательны,убирать их нельзя.
P.S. без tkinter я знаю как сделать есть input,а как сделать с tkinter я не пойму.

```py
from tkinter import *

def func1(event):
    pogoda = w1.get()
    try:
        if pogoda == "плохая":
            raise TypeError
    except TypeError:
        y = w2.get()
        print(y+"Сиди дома")


root = Tk()

root.title("Тест")
root.geometry("350x200")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

puch = Button(text="ПУСК", background="#4C3785", foreground="#fff", font="20", width=12)
puch.place(x=260, y=46, anchor="c", height=40, width=110, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
puch.bind('<Button-1>',func1)

puch2 = Button(text="Ввод2", background="#4C3785", foreground="#fff", font="20", width=12)
puch2.place(x=90, y=140, anchor="c", height=40, width=110, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

w1 = Entry(width=20, fg='black', font='Arial 12')
w1.place(x=10, y=36)
w1L = Label(text="Окно 1", font="20")
w1L.place(x=70, y=6)

w2 = Entry(width=20, fg='black', font='Arial 12')
w2.place(x=10, y=90)
w2L = Label(text="Окно 2", font="20")
w2L.place(x=70, y=60)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Работу программы с графическим интерфейсом нельзя приостановить, можно только принудительно устанавливать фокус во второе поле ввода, если поле ввода теряет фокус (но для этого нужно отслеживать состояние программы, т.е. по сути написать небольшой конечный автомат). Эмуляция поведения консоли в окне - это только лишнее усложнение кода. Это вам нужно по заданию, или вы сами так хотите?

Comment: Сам хочу.Делаю простой графический интерфейс для программы.Оригинальный код скинуть не могу.

Comment: Если просто сделать графический интерфейс - то нет смысла полностью тянуть "особенности" консольного интерфейса. Стоит просто сделать два окна ввода и одну кнопку, и проверку правильности делать при нажатии на кнопку, а там уже можно переводить фокус на окно ввода с неправильными данными.

Comment: Переводить фокус,я новичек в этом.Пока ещё не во всё врубаюсь.Может напишите в виде кода что имеете ввиду.

Comment: Я в общем понял, что у вас в оригинале сначала один input, потом input внутри except. Я не понимаю зачем это. Если бы был пример как в исходной программе, а не про погоду, я бы возможно что-то подсказал.

Comment: Да,вы поняли правильно.Вы дали мне правильною мысль что нет смысла полностью тянуть особенности консольного интерфейса.Буду думать в этом направлении.